# Immersed submanifolds of same dimension

Tags: differential-geometry, manifolds, smooth-manifolds

Suppose $S\subseteq M$ is an immersed submanifold such that $\dim S = \dim M$ (and $S$ and $M$ are connected). Is it true that $S$ is diffeomorphic to $M$?

Comment: Welcome to MSE. It will be more likely that you will get an answer if you show us that you made an effort.

Answer (score 3):

Ofcourse not. Consider $\mathbb{R}$ and  $\mathbb{R}\setminus \{0\}$. Only one of them is connected so they are not even homeomorphic.

Comment: what about if they are connected? In my case both are connected.

Comment: Even then it's not true. Consider $\mathbb{S}^2$ and the upper hemisphere. Both are connected, but only one of them is simply connected.

Answer (score 1):

It is a direct conclusion from the immersion lemma that $S$ and $M$ are local diffeomorphic:

Let $f:S \rightarrow M$ a smooth map and $x\in S$. Then $f$ is an immersion at $x$ if and only if $\text{dim} S - \text{dim} M  =: p\leq 0$ and there exist open neighbourhoods $U$ of $x$ and $V$ of $f(x)$, and a diffeomorphism $\phi$ of $V$ onto a product $U \times \Omega$ with $\Omega$ a open set of $\Bbb R ^p$ with $0\in \Omega$, such that
$$ \phi \circ f =i_1 $$
on $U$, where $i_1: x \mapsto (x,0)$ is the inclusion map on $U\times \Omega$.

In your case $p=0$.

In general, they are not global diffeomorphic.